# Show div on Submit button

Tags: jsp

This question might have been asked many times, I have been having difficulty in applying approach which are given on different websites.

I have a JSP page which contains a search field

```
 ---------------------
|                     |   Type a Character to Search from the Database
|                     |  
 ---------------------

             =============
            |   Submit    |           
             =============
```

When the user types in a character and clicks on the Submit button, I am calling a different JSP "xyz.jsp" like

```
    <div id="searchPage">
    <%@include file="searchResult.jsp"%>
    </div>
```

My requirement is When the page gets loaded, it should display only the search text box and a submit button. When he/she click on the submit button, the div which is including another jsp should get called and displayed.

**Note**

***I need to retain the value entered by the user in the search text field on the click on submit button.***

Code for search page

```
<div id="Search1">
    <aui:form action="......" method="post" name="searchForm" id="searchFormId">

        <aui:input id='name' name="name" label="Student Name" type="text"       value=""   size="50"/>

    </aui:form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showResult(){

    var ele = document.getElementById("Search1");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "block";
      }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't matter if its in jsp or php or asp. the method is the same. you should use java script. when the page initially loads you should already have the div just hidden. when the user clicks the submit button. load the result into the div and change the display to true. I hope this helps.